# Analyzing Context Switch in Multithread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdthread

Is there any way to analyze timing of context switch in multithread? While learning about multithread, I often see figures such as

[this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1271904/Programming-Concurrency-in-Cplusplus-Part-1)

[image]

[this](https://www.logicbig.com/quick-info/programming/multi-threading.html)

[image]

or [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j5e_multithreading.html)

[image]

Is there any way to read and visualize the context switch timing during program execution so that I'm able to see for example : how many duration is spent on Task X before it switch into Task Y, then how many duration is spent on it before switched into Task X again, or if the duration is not calculable, how to get notification that says "Task X is stopped, switch to Task Y"

Comment: Which OS is this for?

Comment: Im trying to analyze multithread performance in embedded system based on DebianJessie

Comment: This might be better suited to Unix and Linux stack exchange site.  Because there's certainly nothing available within the C++ language to observe those things, and no amount of instrumentation can accomplish this (the thread will be ambivalent about context switches) so it'll be an OS-specific thing to trace them.   e.g. of answers over there:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313424/record-time-of-every-process-or-thread-context-switch